# React Functional component html5 video player capture events

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to capture events from an html `<video/>` tag. I have set a ref to it, and using a `useEffect` am trying to capture the events. However, i beleive I am not handling the ref correctly and am not capturing any of the events. Can someone spot my error?

```
  const elementRef = useRef(null);
  function handleEvent(event) {
    console.log(`${event.type}\n`);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      elementRef.addEventListener('loadstart', handleEvent);
      elementRef.addEventListener('progress', handleEvent);
      elementRef.addEventListener('canplay', handleEvent);
      elementRef.addEventListener('canplaythrough', handleEvent);
      elementRef.addEventListener('ended', handleEvent);
      elementRef.addEventListener('pause', handleEvent);
      elementRef.addEventListener('play', handleEvent);
      elementRef.addEventListener('playing', handleEvent);
      elementRef.addEventListener('ratechange', handleEvent);
      elementRef.addEventListener('seeking', handleEvent);
      elementRef.addEventListener('stalled', handleEvent);
    };
  }, [elementRef]);
```

in my `return` i have `<video controls src={FirstVid} poster={Poster} width="620" ref={(el) => (elementRef.current = el)}/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the return of `useEffect` only for cleanup (`removeEventListener`s). Add listeners before the return.

Edit: I never heard of using a function as the value of the `ref` prop

```
<video controls src={FirstVid} poster={Poster} width="620" ref={elementRef}/>
```

Then

```
elementRef.current.addEventListener('loadstart', handleEvent);
```

But I have not read all the docs so no guarantees...

I would try something like the following:

```
const elementRef = useRef(null);
  function handleEvent(event) {
    // use a switch/case to check for each event
    console.log(`${event.type}\n`);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
      ['loadstart', /* all the other events */].forEach(event => 
        elementRef.current.addEventListener(event, handleEvent);
      )
      return () => {/* remove all event listeners here */}
  }, [elementRef]);
return <video controls src={FirstVid} poster={Poster} width="620" ref={elementRef}/>
```

Comment: If i pull it out of the effect it returns  a "elementref is Not a function" error, as elementref is defined as null right above

Comment: Yes I see, worked great. I guess the issuen was with how i set the ref. Thanks for the response. I was struggling

Comment: You are very welcome. 1 final edit. I switched my code sample to use an Array of events to make the sample more DRY

Comment: I also suggested you use a `switch` in the handler to define specific behavior for each event

Comment: Thanks @Abraham Labkovsky, I will implement a switch